# SVG Path conversion to Android Drawable fails

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

The svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="382"
   height="350"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1">
  <path
     style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero"
     d="M 190.46289,1.9140625 A 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 113.5957,79.855469 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 113.7832,84.326172 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 80.462891,76.914062 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 3.5957031,154.85547 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 60.125,228.85742 a 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 -11.529297,40.99805 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 77.880857,76.92969 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 64.4668,-35.50196 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 65.5332,35.50196 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 76.86719,-77.94141 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 -10.49805,-38.25 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 55.49805,-74.75 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 -77.88086,-76.929688 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 -32.44727,7.470704 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 0.32813,-7.541016 A 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 190.46289,1.9140625 Z M 105.5,98.5 l 170,0 c 8.31,0 15,6.69 15,15 l 0,126 c 0,8.31 -6.69,15 -15,15 l -101.05859,0 -72.81446,35.29688 L 130.59961,254.5 105.5,254.5 c -0.84458,0 -1.66687,-0.0859 -2.47266,-0.21875 l -1.72265,0.002 0,-0.38476 C 95.051207,252.09077 90.5,246.35121 90.5,239.5 l 0,-126 c 0,-8.31 6.69,-15 15,-15 z"
     id="svg_6" />
</svg>
```

looks like this in all tested browsers and Inkscape:
[image]

If I convert it using the [awesome svg2android tool](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/), I get the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="382dp"
    android:height="350dp"
    android:viewportWidth="382"
    android:viewportHeight="350">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M 190.46289,1.9140625 A 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 113.5957,79.855469
77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 113.7832,84.326172 77.437241,77.375557
89.625608 0 0 80.462891,76.914062 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0
3.5957031,154.85547 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 60.125,228.85742 a
77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 -11.529297,40.99805 77.437241,77.375557
89.625608 0 0 77.880857,76.92969 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0
64.4668,-35.50196 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 65.5332,35.50196
77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 76.86719,-77.94141 77.437241,77.375557
89.625608 0 0 -10.49805,-38.25 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 55.49805,-74.75
77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 -77.88086,-76.929688 77.437241,77.375557
89.625608 0 0 -32.44727,7.470704 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0
0.32813,-7.541016 A 77.437241,77.375557 89.625608 0 0 190.46289,1.9140625 Z M
105.5,98.5 l 170,0 c 8.31,0 15,6.69 15,15 l 0,126 c 0,8.31 -6.69,15 -15,15 l
-101.05859,0 -72.81446,35.29688 L 130.59961,254.5 105.5,254.5 c -0.84458,0
-1.66687,-0.0859 -2.47266,-0.21875 l -1.72265,0.002 0,-0.38476 C
95.051207,252.09077 90.5,246.35121 90.5,239.5 l 0,-126 c 0,-8.31 6.69,-15 15,-15
z" />
</vector>
```

which looks like this in the Android Studio preview:
[image]

I cannot spot the error in the path data. Can you? (I also copied the svg path data directly to the xml which yields the same rendering)

Comment: You don't say whether or not it looks okay when the app is run.  Ie. is it just the preview in Android Studio that is not rendering correctly?  I agree that the two path definitions look identical.

Comment: Both preview and rendering on my phone are incorrect while the svg from Lary does work but it is unclear why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix such broken VectorDrawables using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/de/) (similar to what [Lary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251538/1531708) did but with a full tutorial here):

1. Add the path data from the Android drawable as new path to your Inkscape document
2. Mark the path and click `Path->Simplify`
3. Open the XML Editor (Shift+Ctrl+X), select the path and copy the value of its property "d"
4. Replace your VectorDrawable's pathData with the one copied in the previous step

[image]

Answer (score 2):

there were a problem with you initial svg, i updated it with illustrator, anyway here is the xml for android

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="374dp"
        android:height="344dp"
        android:viewportWidth="374.751"
        android:viewportHeight="344.874">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M186.9,0c-42.7,0.3 -77.1,35.2 -76.9,77.9c0,1.5 0.1,3 0.2,4.5c-10.4,-4.9 -21.8,-7.5 -33.3,-7.4c-42.7,0.3 -77.1,35.2 -76.9,77.9c0.3,34.5 23.3,64.7 56.5,74c-7.6,12.3 -11.6,26.5 -11.5,41c0.3,42.8 35.1,77.2 77.9,76.9c0,0 0,0 0,0c26.1,-0.2 50.3,-13.5 64.5,-35.5c14.3,22.3 39.1,35.7 65.5,35.5c42.7,-0.3 77.1,-35.2 76.9,-77.9c-0.1,-13.4 -3.7,-26.6 -10.5,-38.3c33.1,-9.8 55.7,-40.2 55.5,-74.8c-0.3,-42.8 -35.1,-77.2 -77.9,-76.9c0,0 0,0 -0,0c-11.2,0.1 -22.3,2.7 -32.4,7.5c0.2,-2.5 0.3,-5 0.3,-7.5C264.5,34.2 229.6,-0.3 186.9,0C186.9,0 186.9,0 186.9,0zM101.9,96.6h170c8.3,0 15,6.7 15,15v126c0,8.3 -6.7,15 -15,15H170.8l-72.8,35.3l29,-35.3h-25.1c-0.8,0 -1.7,-0.1 -2.5,-0.2l-1.7,0v-0.4c-6.3,-1.8 -10.8,-7.5 -10.8,-14.4v-126C86.9,103.3 93.6,96.6 101.9,96.6z"/>
</vector>
```

(on a side not you can now create vector assert with android studio right click >new > vector asset and you can import svg direclty )

Comment: What was the "problem" that you fixed?  There is nothing ostensibly wrong with the original.  Not explaining what you changed doesn't help the OP or others looking at this question.

Comment: i actually don't know.. i tried adding PhilLab svg to an android project using android sudio vector asset tool, i had the same result than him (when building app, the svg was malformed), i then openned the svg in illustrator re-export it as svg, then reimport it in android project and it worked properly this time ... since the result was there i thought posting it would help PhilLab anyway.

Comment: @LaryCiminera Thanks for the correct svg and especially for the Android Studio update hint! Let's see if we can spot the cause of the error - I will keep the question open for a little while

Comment: If that is the case, then it would appear that Android & AS have a bug in how they interpret some path definition strings.  You should report it on the Android bug tracker. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Answer (score 1):

I created a vector drawable & it works as per the requirement. Used the jpg image attached in the post & converted it to svg using the website http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg. Then I used that svg & created a new Vector asset in Android Studio. It works correctly.

Try the below code

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="364.0"
    android:viewportWidth="386.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#000000" android:strokeColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M178,2.6c-7.9,1.6 -17.9,4.8 -23.8,7.8 -24.9,12.5 -42.1,39.7 -42.2,66.3 0,
        4 -0.2,7.3 -0.5,7.3 -0.2,0 -2.7,-0.9 -5.4,-2 -18.6,-7.3 -43.1,-6.1 -60.9,2.9 -12.6,
        6.4 -23.2,15.8 -30.7,27.1 -20.3,30.7 -15.6,72.7 11.2,98.1 8.8,8.4 17.6,13.6 30.5,
        18.2 1.6,0.6 1.4,1.4 -1.7,7.9 -5.9,12.4 -7.8,22.2 -7.2,36.3 0.8,20 7.5,35.9 20.9,
        50.1 15.6,16.4 39.1,25.7 60.3,23.9 24.2,-2.1 44.2,-13.1 58.3,-32l2.2,-3 2.2,3c3.9,
        5.4 15.4,16.3 21.2,20 25.5,16.3 59.1,16.1 84.1,-0.6 31.7,-21.2 43.4,-62.7 27.5,-96.8 -1.7,
        -3.5 -2.9,-6.5 -2.8,-6.6 0.2,-0.1 3.1,-1.2 6.5,-2.4 16.3,-6 31.9,-20.5 40.2,
        -37.4 6,-12.3 8.1,-21.3 8.1,-34.4 -0.1,-41.5 -31.4,-74.5 -73,-77 -10.4,-0.6 -22,1.1 -31.1,
        4.7 -2.7,1.1 -5.2,2 -5.4,2 -0.3,0 -0.5,-3.7 -0.5,-8.3 -0.1,-33.2 -22.9,-62.8 -56,-72.7 -7.4,
        -2.2 -25.8,-3.6 -32,-2.4zM281,100.7c1.9,1.2 4.4,3.7 5.5,5.5 1.9,3.2 2,5.1 2,70.3 0,
        65.2 -0.1,67.1 -2,70.3 -1.1,1.8 -3.6,4.3 -5.5,5.5 -3.5,2.2 -4.2,2.2 -57.5,2.7l-54,0.5 -28,
        13.9c-33.9,16.7 -40.8,19.9 -39.9,18.3 0.4,-0.6 6.4,-8.1 13.3,-16.5 6.9,-8.4 12.7,-15.7 12.9,
        -16.1 0.2,-0.5 -4.1,-0.7 -9.4,-0.4 -5.3,0.3 -12.2,0.2 -15.3,-0.2 -4.8,-0.6 -6.2,-1.3 -9.7,
        -4.9 -3.6,-3.5 -4.3,-4.9 -4.9,-9.6 -0.3,-3 -0.5,-33.6 -0.3,-68 0.3,-62.3 0.3,-62.5 2.5,-66 2.6,
        -4.1 5.5,-6.1 10.3,-7.1 1.9,-0.4 42.4,-0.6 90,-0.6l86.5,0.2 3.5,2.2z"
    />
</vector>
```

Comment: How did you create the VectorDrawable? Your answer, without further information, doesn't really help the OP or others with similar problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, the upper, right and bottom circles are cut off a little but